# Can't get bootstrap collapse to work in Rails (can't generate a new target-data id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to create a basic event listing site where it will display a list of events in a table format. I was hoping to make every row have a collapse effect with bootstrap. The problem that I'm running into is that I can get the collapse working but only for one single row. Later I learned that Bootstrap identifies each target-data id differently, so I've been trying to figure out how to put a unique id into the loop. Any clue? Here's what I have so far.

```
   <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>start time</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <% @events.group_by(&:date).each do |date, events| %>
   <tr><td colspan="100"><h1><%= date.strftime("%B %d")  %></h1></td></tr>
   <% events.each do |event| %>
   </tbody>

        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="<%= event.id %>" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td><%= event.title %></td>
            <td><%= event.link %></td>
            <td><%= event.start_time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p") + "PST" %></td>
 <td class="hiddenRow">
            <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="<%= event.id %>">
            <%= event.description%> </div>
        </td>
        </tr>


  <% end %>

  <% end %>



</table>
```

Comment: To start with you have a nested `tbody` element that should be removed and you are not printing the id's, use `<%= event.id %>` instead of `<% event.id %>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried fixing the event.id and it's still not working :(

Comment: I've also edit the code, it's weird because if i put id="demo" and then change the target data id to "#demo" it will work but only for the 1st row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, basically the event didn't have an id in the active record, so I had to use .each_with_index to generate an index for a new id. Hope this helps anyone that is struggling.